# Propel follow relationship backwards

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I have two tables in my db, that I have reverse engineered with propel reverse, one of which has the other as a foreign key.  Here is part of the sql used to create the answer table:

```
CREATE TABLE answer (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
run_id INT NOT NULL,

FOREIGN KEY (run_id)
    REFERENCES run(id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Now I am creating a method in RunQuery that has to join on the Answer table:

```
RunQuery::create()->join('Answer')
```

**I get error:**

> Uncaught exception 'PropelException' with message 'Unknown relation Answer on the Run table'

**In the Apache logs**

I've looked in the generated schema, and it lists run as a foreign key of answer...  How do I make this join happen?

Cheers,
-Scott!

Answer (score 0):

Propel should have generated  `joinAnswer()` and `joinWithAnswer()` methods (join with will hydrate your result object), but sometimes i have to use the table name instead of the phpName that you're trying to use, so, `RunQuery::create()->join('answer')` should do the trick.